# Sort a List of Points by Slope

Tags: c#, sorting

In looking around StackOverflow I've found a couple examples of sorting lists by one attribute, or by distances between points, but none by slope. I am not very familiar with C# and would love some help.

I have a list of points:
(1,1) (2,5) (3,3) (7,1)

This would look something like this:

```
--x-----
--------
---x----
--------
-x-----x
--------
```

I would like to calculate the slope from the left-most point (1,1) to each other point:

- (1,1) to (2,5)
- (1,1) to (3,3)
- (1,1) to (7,1)

and then sort them in descending order.

Slope is determined by the gain in y, divided by the gain in x ("rise over run").

The slopes would result in the following:

- (1,1) to (2,5) => 4 / 1 = 4
- (1,1) to (3,3) => 2 / 2 = 1
- (1,1) to (7,1) => 0 / 6 = 0

How can I do this with C#?

I've been able to do this: `numbers.OrderBy(p => p.X);` and am thinking the solution should be something like this:

```
Point anchorPoint = new Point(1,1);
numbers = numbers.OrderBy(p => (p.Y - anchorPoint.Y)/(p.X - anchorPoint.X));
```

but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: What happens when you try your solution?

Comment: A slope is between two points - do you want to order by "slope between point N and the next one" or "slope between point N and the previous one"? What would you want to do with the one at the end, where there effectively isn't a slope? Perhaps you *actually* want to have a sequence of pairs, and order that sequence of pairs by their slope?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It looks like they have a sequence of pairs.. each pair consists of the `anchorPoint`.  Since `anchorPoint` is implied in each pair, that could be why they are not storing that point explicitly.

Comment: Is your "anchor point" always the first point in the list, and you want to order the _remaining_ points by their slops relative to the first point?

Comment: @DStanley: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great answers.

I figured out my error: typing.

I was trying to return my sorted results back into the list I was ordering. There is a disconnect between List and OrderedList. To fix this, I appended the `.ToList()` call.

`numbers = numbers.OrderBy(p => (p.Y - anchorPoint.Y)/(p.X - anchorPoint.X)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You're close - you just need to keep the "anchor" point as the first in the list and put any "infinite" slopes at the front:

```
Point anchorPoint = numbers[0];
var query = 
     numbers.Select((p,i) => new {p,i})  // to get the index of each point
            .OrderBy(pi => pi.i == 0 ? 0 : 1)  // keep the first point first
            .ThenByDescending(pi => (pi.p.X == anchorPoint.X) ? double.PositiveInfinity 
                                                              : (pi.p.Y * 1.0 - anchorPoint.Y)/(pi.p.X - anchorPoint.X))  // infinite slopes first, the finite slopes descending
            .Select(pi => p);
```

Note that I multiply one of the values by 1.0 to convert from *integer* divison to *floating point* division.

You could also "skip" the first point, order the rest, and then concatenate the results:

```
var query = 
     numbers.Take(1).Concat(
     numbers.Skip(1)
            .OrderByDescending(p => (p.X == anchorPoint.X) ? double.PositiveInfinity 
                                                           : (p.Y * 1.0 - anchorPoint.Y)/(p.X - anchorPoint.X))
     );
```

which is a little cleaner because you don't have the projection to an anonymous type to include the index.